# Changing global variable from Socket.io Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

Client code:

```
var app = {
    data: {
        user: null
    }
};

var client = {
    connect: function () {
        client.data.socket.on('connectCallback', function (obj) {
            if (obj.userFound) {
                app.data.user = obj.user;
                return app.data.user;
            }
        });
        /** 
        Other callbacks 
        **/
    };
};
```

`app.data.user` is always `null`, I also tried a second function to change the variable. The obj returned by the server isn't `null`, I already checked that.

using code like `var foo = client.data.socket.on` didn't work because than foo is a socket.io object. Also passing a custom callback function didn't work , because i can't pass it to the socket.io callback.

**I don't wan't to do an ajax call, as some people think.**

Comment: *"`app.data.user` is always `null`"* In what code? You haven't shown where/how you use it, which is a pretty important part of the question.

Comment: I use developer tools to debug the code, after the callback was called I use the console to check the variable. There is also other code which changes the content of my page which is executed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `app.data.user` is always `null`, I also tried a second function to change the variable. The `obj` returned by the server isn't `null`, I already checked that.

That means there are two possibilities:

1. You're checking `app.data.user` **before** the callback has occurred, or
2. Even though `obj` isn't `null`, either `obj.userFound` is falsey, or `obj.user` is `null`

My suspicion would be #1: You're checking the value before the callback occurs, but as you haven't shown your code where you're trying to use `app.data.user` and getting `null`, I can't say for certain.

Comment: I already checked #2, obj isnt null and obj.userFound is true.
  #1 cant be the problem because I've added breakpoints to check when I have to check the variable

Comment: @LarsUnbekannt: And then there was one. :-) (Possibility, that is.)

Comment: There is a third one: user is set to null after the callback was called.

Comment: it isn't set to null anywhere

Comment: @MauricePerry: Ah, good point! And a fourth: `app` is getting shadowed. And a fifth: `app.data` is being reassigned after the callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what means ´app´ is getting shadowed ?. #5 app.data is never reassigned in my code.

Comment: @LarsUnbekannt: "shadowing" is where there's a variable declaration that hides one in a containing scope. For instance, if you have `var a = 42; function foo() { var a = 67; console.log(a); } foo();` you see 67, not 42, because `a` is shadowed inside `foo`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah ok, `app` isn't getting shadowed

Comment: @LarsUnbekannt: Well, one of these things is happening, or something that isn't clear from the code. The only thing that will reveal what's happening is to debug it with the debugger built into your browser, we can't help any further with what's in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I've checked all this points with my debugger. There isn't really more code executed than shown in the first post.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I only run the code seen in my first Post

Comment: @LarsUnbekannt: *"There isn't really more code executed than shown in the first post"* Of course there is -- *something* is calling `client.connect`, right? As you said you see the callback occur.

Comment: @LarsUnbekannt: I see you've "accepted" this answer -- does that mean you've found what it was, and it was one of the things above? (If not, probably best to un-accept the answer...)